# why is my last else condition not executing correctly

Tags: c++, if-statement

why is it when I input anything other than int I get 0 is an even number, the plan was if the user enters something that's not an integer it should output invalid input

```
cout << "Enter an integer: ";
cin >> input;

if(input % 2 == 0) {
    cout << input  << " is an even "
    "number" << endl;
}else if(input % 2 != 0) {
    cout << input  << " is an odd "
    "number" << endl;
}else {
    cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: If you don't give an integer input, what do you expect `cin >> input` to do? What value do you think `input` has?

Comment: `input` is declared to be an `int`. How can it hold anything other than a number?

Comment: I see both of your points. It's an int what else would it hold that's a great point. I think I got it confused with the switch the default statement. Anyways, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin >> input` is an operation that can fail, and if it fails the `input` variable does not contain a useful value. You can check whether it succeeded by [converting `cin` to `bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool):

```cpp
cin >> input;
if (!cin) {
    cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
} else if (input % 2 && input != 0) {
   ...
```

Or, since `cin >> input` returns the `cin` object again, this is equivalent:

```
if (!(cin >> input)) {
    cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
} else if (input % 2 && input != 0) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. If I'm being honest I don't think I needed that last condition because I should be expecting only integers. Again, Thank You!

Comment: @an0nymOusan0nymOus -- you don't need the last condition because `input` can only be an integer. The possibility that someone might type some incorrect text doesn't change that. Its type is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that works thanks to jtbandes

Exercise - Write a program to check whether a given number is ODD or Even

```
cout << "Even/Odd Program" << endl;
int input;

cout << "Enter an integer: ";
cin >> input;

 if (!(cin >> input)) {
     cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
 } else if(input % 2 == 0) {
    cout << input  << " is an even "
    "number" << endl;
}else
    cout << input  << " is an odd "
    "number" << endl;

return 0;
```

}